# Add field and groupby in in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I want to be able to add a new field in aggregation and return the average value of all records with the same session ID. Something like this, but it's not possible to use a groupby inside addfield:

```
{
                $addFields: {
                    sessionData: {
                        $group: {
                            _id: {
                                "sessionId": "$sessionId"
                            },
                            avgScrollDepth: { $avg: "$scrollDepthChange" },
                            totalSessionLength: { $max: "$scrollDepthChange" }
                        }
                    }
                }
},
```

**Edit:**
Lets say these are the documents:

```
{
    "sessionId": 1,
    "sessionDepth": 1
},
{
    "sessionId": 1,
    "sessionDepth": 2
},
{
    "sessionId": 1,
    "sessionDepth": 3
}
```

I would want to return documents like this:

```
{
    "sessionId": 1,
    "sessionDepth": 1,
    "totalSessionLength": 3
},
{
    "sessionId": 1,
    "sessionDepth": 2,
    "totalSessionLength": 3
},
{
    "sessionId": 1,
    "sessionDepth": 3,
    "totalSessionLength": 3
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

1. We store inside `tmp` variable all grouped documents
2. Count `totalSessionLength`
3. Flatten `tmp` variable with `$unwind` operator
4. Add `totalSessionLength` into final result

---

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$sessionId",
      totalSessionLength: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      tmp: {
        $push: {
          "sessionId": "$sessionId",
          "sessionDepth": "$sessionDepth"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$tmp"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "_id": 0,
      "sessionId": "$tmp.sessionId",
      "sessionDepth": "$tmp.sessionDepth",
      "totalSessionLength": "$totalSessionLength"
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GpwE3ab43FK)

## Generic way:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$sessionId",
      totalSessionLength: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      tmp: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$tmp"
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          "$tmp",
          {
            totalSessionLength: "$totalSessionLength"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/L7p3a9nV-Os)